# Name scope confusion

Tags: pattern-matching, scoping

Sorry for the too ambiguous title.

First consider a following code snippet.

```
x = "x"; y = "y";

kk[] := Module[ {q, w, m},
    q[a_] := a + 1;
    w[a_] := a^2;
    m[Global`x] = q;
    m[Global`y] = w;
    m
]
```

With this function `kk` I can write code like this,

```
kk[][x][1]    (* output -> 2 *)
kk[][y][2]    (* output -> 4 *)
```

as expected.

However, I want to change the name of the global variables `x` and `y` to those of the local variables `q` and `w`. Thus, consider a below snippet.

q = "x"; w = "y";

```
kk2[] := Module[ {q, w, m},
    q[a_] := a + 1;
    w[a_] := a^2;
    m[Global`q] = q;
    m[Global`w] = w;
    m
]
```

Note that the only change to the above code is the global variable names `x` and `y`.
However, this function `kk2` does not work as expected anymore. Can you explain?

The output I got was,

```
kk2[][q][1] (* unevaluated *)
kk2[][w][2]
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: add `[]` to each `kk2` calls as pointed by m_goldberg

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with such constructs? This "feels" like trying to do *something* that has a better solution. In any case, do `Module[{q}, Global`q]` and observe the result...

Comment: @rasher I tried your suggestion. It returns local q instead of global one. Can I ask you why?

Comment: Search documentation for "Modularity", first hit has a tutorial that might help you understand. Also read the "common pitfalls" question at this site. And again, always good to include in your question *what* you're trying to accomplish (and *why* in this case). Most times trying to use global state locally pulling it into a function raises eyebrows...

Comment: Also try `Module[{q}, Context[q]]`, which gives ``Global` ``. That may be confusing, as `q` is of course supposed to be used as a local variable. But `Module` resolves naming conflicts by giving `q` a unique name, rather than by putting `q` in another context, or something like that. If you want to refer to the "global" `q`, you can do something like `Symbol["q"]`, but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: `kk[x][1]` and `kk[y][2]` don't evaluate. Should they not be `kk[][x][1]` and `kk[][y][2]`?

Comment: @rasher This post it the underlying reason for this approach. Please read this post. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45916/proper-way-to-generate-a-higher-order-function-with-a-proper-scoping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Module` works different than scoping constructs in other languages.

Here's a simpler example which already gives a clue of what happens:

```
x=3; Module[{x}, {x, Global`x, Context[x]}]
(*
==> {x$81, x$81, Global`}
*)
```

You see, no matter whether you prefix it with `` Global` ``, `x` gets replaced with `x$81`, which indeed also has global context.

Indeed, this is how `Module` works:

1. The parsing code generates references to the symbol `` Global`x `` whenever you refer to `x` with or without `` Global` `` prefix (this is assuming you didn't use any commands changing the current context, of course). Note that symbol resolution already happens at this step.
2. When the `Module` statement is executed, each instance of `` Global`x `` occurring *lexically* in the expression is replaced with a new variable, here `x$81` (the exact name varies from call to call, guaranteeing that the name is unique). So technically, there's not a new scope introduced, but a variable replacement happens.
3. Now the code with the replaced variable is executed.
4. If no references to the introduced "local" variables remain, they are removed again.

You can also see this in action by explicitly constructing the variable name:

```
x=3; Module[{x}, Symbol["x"]]
(*
==> 3
*)
```

Here, at the time `Module` does symbol replacement, the expression doesn't yet contain the symbol`` Global`x ``, but only the expression `Symbol["x"]` where the `"x"` is just a string. Therefore the replacement step doesn't replace anything, and during evaluation `Symbol["x"]` creates a reference to `` Global`x ``, not to `` Global`x$81 `` (or whatever the "local" variable is called this time). And since `` Global`x `` has been assigned the value `3`, it evaluates to that value.

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

I am quite unable to understand why you just don't write

```
kk[q][a_] := a + 1
kk[w][a_] := a^2
```

This gives

```
{kk[q][1], kk[w][2]}
```

> ```
> {2, 4}
> ```

Wouldn't the above satisfy your needs?

Comment: Could you read this post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45916/proper-way-to-generate-a-higher-order-function-with-a-proper-scoping ? This is the underlying reason I tried this approach.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
 q = "x"; w = "y";
 kk[] := Module[{q, w, m},
    q[a_] := a + 1;
    w[a_] := a^2;
    m[Symbol["q"]] = q;
    m[Symbol["w"]] = w;
     m]
```

Cant imagine why you'd want to do this though.

Comment: Could you read this post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45916/proper-way-to-generate-a-higher-order-function-with-a-proper-scoping ? This is the underlying reason I tried this approach